# With variadic function templates can we design a function that can be called with at least 2 arguments?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I am just beginning to understand variadic function templates.
Is it possible to have a definition where the generic case (handling recursion) is written with 2 or more arguments? That is, I am wondering can I write something as follows :

```
template <class T>
void min(T val1, T val2) { return val1>val2 ? val2 : val1 ; }

template <class T, class... Others>
void min(T a1, T a2, Others ... others) {
    // implementation
    T a = a1 > a2 ? a2 : a1 ;
    // min(a, first-element-in-others, all-elems-in-others-except-first) ;
}
```

If this is possible, can someone show me how?

Comment: Yep. Did you try to compile it? This seems fine...

Comment: *"first-element-in-others, all-elems-in-others-except-first"* This just sounds like "all elements in `others`", which is `others...`. You might also want to look into *fold expressions*.

Comment: @Elliott what do I write inside the commented `min` function call

Comment: When you do this, a common pattern to avoid repetition is: `T min (T a1, T a2, Ts ... as) { return min(min(a1, a2), as...);}` that way you rely only on the base function to do the actual calculation.

Comment: @user3282758 I think you might want to change the `void` to `T` there, otherwise the compiler might throw an error when you try to use the function.

Comment: @ HolyBlackCat I tried defing as `void min(T a1, T a2, Others ... others) {
        T a = a1 > a2 ? a2 : a1 ; 
        min(a, others...) ; 
}`. This did not work

Comment: @user3282758, basically what you've written is fine, but to convert from pseudocode: `return min(a, others...);`

Comment: @ Ruks  yes changed that `void` to `T`

Comment: @Elliott, the following is not working `return min(a, others...) `

Comment: and the return type is `T` for both functions? and that was the only edit made to the code in your questions?

Comment: @Elliott YES.thats the only change

Comment: @user3282758, it seems to work. check out this [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/r5K7YsYGK)

Comment: Notice that [`std::min(std::initializer_list<T>)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min) exists.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this, perhaps?

```cpp
// C++11 or above
template <typename T>
T min(T const& val1, T const& val2) {
    return val1 > val2 ? val2 : val1;
}

template <typename T, typename... Others>
T min(T const& a1, T const& a2, Others... others) {
    T const a = min(a1, a2);
    return min(a, others...);
}
```

It also seems to compile.

If you want to try it for yourself, here you go:

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://godbolt.org/z/EfMnhGhvq)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete code which works (note, that by convention `min` function should only require operator `<`):

```
template <class T>
constexpr T min(T val1, T val2) { return val1 < val2 ? val1 : val2 ; }

template <class T, class... Others>
constexpr T min(T a1, T a2, Others... others) {
    T a = min(a1, a2);
    return min(a, others...);
}
```

Note, that you might want to accept arguments by const reference, but I've left it for another day.

Comment: This is the same code as mine. I am using gcc compiler for c++11. Code compilation gives following error `/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algobase.h:249:17: error: ‘__comp’ cannot be used as a function
  249 |       if (__comp(__b, __a))
      |           ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
`

Comment: @user3282758, this isn't a complete program. Your errors are coming from other parts of your code. Possibly you've included `<algorithm>` and used `namespace std;` which would cause big issues here. either way, this code is certainly fine. You've been given lots of links to live code to prove this already.

Answer (score 1):

You were very close to actual implementation, but messed up return type.

```cpp
template <class T>
T min(T a, T b) 
{
    return std::min(a, b);
}

template <class T, class... Others>
T min(T a1, T a2, Others ... others) {
    return min(min(a1, a2), others...);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/5dGeW79Md

Comment: YES got it, actually my implementation was messing up with the std::min...I changed my function name and now this works.  @Marek R your solution suddenly helped me

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to return `T` and to not write `using namespace std` or you'll clash with the standard library function, `min`.

```
#include <algorithm>

template <class T>
T min (T a) 
{
    return a;
}

template <class T, class... Ts>
T min (T a1, T a2, Ts ... as)
{
    return min(std::min(a1, a2), as...);
}
```